# LinearLayout fails when set to be parent of ScrollView

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to make that a LinearLayout displays an ad in the bottom of the screen. It's a banner ad.
I have tried many combinations and when I put the LinearLayout above the Scrollview in the layout.xml hierarchy, I get an error of the type "ScrollView can host only one direct child" and the app crashes.

I am able to make the app to work by putting the ScrollView above the LinearLayout of the ad, but in this case the ad appears below all the buttons while it should appear in the hierarchy over the scrolling buttons, at the bottom of the screen.

How can I manage to make that the banner appears at the bottom of the screen with the scrolling buttons above?

This is an excerpt of my main.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- This file is /res/layout/main.xml   Era LinearLayout-->

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <!--  
        <com.facebook.ads.AdView
            android:id="@id/banner"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
             />
    -->


      <ScrollView
          android:id="@+id/scroll"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content">

       <LinearLayout
           android:id="@+id/banner_container"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
           android:orientation="vertical"
           app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

          <Button
              android:id="@+id/holaPlayerBtn"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:background="@drawable/custom_button_yellow"
              android:text="@string/hola"
              android:textColor="#000000"
              android:textStyle="bold" />

          <Button
              android:id="@+id/adiosPlayerBtn"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:background="@drawable/custom_button_yellow"
              android:text="@string/adios"
              android:textColor="#000000"
              android:textStyle="bold" />


          ... many other buttons here ...

          <Button
              android:id="@+id/hastaprontoPlayerBtn"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:background="@drawable/custom_button_yellow"
              android:text="@string/hasta_pronto"
              android:textColor="#000000"
              android:textStyle="bold" />

       </LinearLayout>
   </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need set fillViewport :

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scroll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fillViewport="true" <!-- Here --> >
    ...

 </ScrollView>
```

What is fillViewPort ? References from [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView) android:fillViewport. Defines whether the scrollview should stretch its content to fill the viewport.

Comment: I did as you mention... no changes. :(

Answer (score 0):

> Here is the Solution:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- This file is /res/layout/main.xml   Era LinearLayout-->

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/banner_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/holaPlayerBtn"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
                android:text="hola"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/adiosPlayerBtn"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
                android:text="adios"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            // Add more buttons/views as your wish.

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    // This will always remain at bottom.
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/hastaprontoPlayerBtn"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
        android:text="hasta_pronto"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: With this the UI is not rendered and the app crashes while starting

Comment: Yes, I've tried with your changes... now the IU is rendered and the App starts... but there is no banner ad at the bottom. :-(

Comment: `hastaprontoPlayerBtn` this will remain on the bottom. you can place your banner ad by replacing that button.

Comment: Yes I think I know what you mean... look at the .xml in my solution I think it's the same as you mention... thanks for your kind help. :)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it work as expected:
The winning main.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

       <ScrollView
          android:id="@+id/scroll"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="0dp"
           android:layout_weight="1">

         <LinearLayout
             android:id="@+id/button_container"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:orientation="vertical">

              <Button
              android:id="@+id/holaPlayerBtn"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:background="@drawable/custom_button_yellow"
              android:text="@string/hola"
              android:textColor="#000000"
              android:textStyle="bold" />

          <Button
              android:id="@+id/adiosPlayerBtn"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:background="@drawable/custom_button_yellow"
              android:text="@string/adios"
              android:textColor="#000000"
              android:textStyle="bold" />

 <!-- Lots of buttons are placed here -->

          <Button
              android:id="@+id/hastaprontoPlayerBtn"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:background="@drawable/custom_button_yellow"
              android:text="@string/hasta_pronto"
              android:textColor="#000000"
              android:textStyle="bold" />

              </LinearLayout>
       </ScrollView>
  <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/banner_container"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="vertical">
  </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```